# if there are two regions enclosed by two lines how do I find area

Tags: calculus, integration, graphing-functions

**Equations**

$y=x^3$ and $y=x$

obviously when graphing this, it would spit two areas formed.

Thus the "regular" way to set up the integral would be the following: $\int_{-1}^0(x^3-x)+\int_0^1(x-x^3)$ which gives me 0.5

But

how do I write this within one integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{-1}^1 |x^3 - x|\text{d}x$$

Note that in order to actually solve this integral you'd still split the integral into the two pieces you originally had.

Answer (score 1):

Absolute values.  You only care about the distance between $x$ and $x^3$, so use the "distance between" operator (a.k.a. absolute value).

Comment: where do I stick the absolute value symbols in? thanks!

Comment: I would say, "see the other answer", but it's been deleted.  If you want to know the distance between $a$ and $b$, it's $|a-b|$ (and if $a$ or $b$ stand for some complicated expression, you might want some parentheses, $|(a)-(b)|$, but that looks silly when there's only one term).  So, $|x - x^3|$ (or $|x^3 - x|$; same value).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, a change of variable (y=-x) yields
$$
\int_{-1}^0 x^3-x\,dx
=-\int_{1}^0 y-y^3\,dy
=\int_{0}^1 y-y^3\,dy
$$
So,
$$
\int_{-1}^0(x^3-x)\,dx+\int_0^1(x-x^3)\,dx = 2\int_0^1(x-x^3)\,dx
$$